# How can I implement instant search within jQuery Accordions

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-ui, sharepoint-2013

I am really new with JavaScript, I am trying to bind Json data to an accordion but so far it seems that i haven't been able to do it correctly. 
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jlriverayuso/hf9cdwjv/13/)

Also how would i be able to instantly search within the accordions?

```js
var contacts = [{
    "Title": "Change Management",
    "Definition": "Collective term for all approaches to prepare and support individuals, teams, and organizations in making organizational change. The most common change drivers include&#58; technological evolution, process reviews, crisis, and consumer habit changes; pressure from new business entrants, acquisitions, mergers, and organizational restructuring. It includes methods that redirect or redefine the use of resources, business process, budget allocations, or other modes of operation that significantly change a company or organization. Organizational change management (OCM) considers the full organization and what needs to change,[3] while change management may be used solely to refer to how people and teams are affected by such organizational transition. It deals with many different disciplines, from behavioral and social sciences to information technology and business solutions. In a project-management context, the term &quot;change management&quot; may be used as an alternative to change control processes where in changes to the scope of a project are formally introduced and approved."
  },
  {
    "Title": "Testing glossary",
    "Definition": "Testing Text 1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum"
  },
  {
    "Title": "More info",
    "Definition": "Testing Text 1 but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain"
  },
  {
    "Title": "Category 2",
    "Definition": "Testing Text 1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."
  }
];

var departmentlist = new Array();
$.each(contacts, function(i, contact) {
  //insert the departments
  if (contact.Title != null && $('#' + contact.Title).length == 0) {
    $('#accordion').append('<h3 id=' + contact.Title + '><a href="#">' + contact.Title + '</a></h3>');
    departmentlist.push(contact.Title);
  }
  //insert contacts in the accordion
  $('#' + contact.Title).after('<p><a' + contact.Definition + '</a></p>');
});
$.each(departmentlist, function(i, list) {
$("#" + list).nextUntil("h3").wrapAll("<div></div>");
});
});
$(function() {
      $("#accordion").accordion({
        collapsible: true,
        active: false,
      });
```

```html
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="contactlist">
  <div id="accordion">

  </div>
</div>
```

**Update 2**

With the following [code worked](http://jsfiddle.net/jlriverayuso/huoLfv0q/5) by @Twisty. This is what I currently see in the [SharePoint Site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgYbN.png) it seems that the only thing still not working is the Search/Highlight.

Comment: Your code has an error, "{
  "message": "SyntaxError: expected expression, got '}'",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 49,
  "colno": 2
}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What do you mean by 'Instant Search'? Search the Titles? How do you want results to appear?

Comment: @Twisty i would like to implement a search like this [link](https://jsfiddle.net/jlriverayuso/8avofxnb/). essentially i want to search within the content and open/close the accordions while highlighting

Comment: @NathanielFlick the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jlriverayuso/hf9cdwjv/13/) seems to come up fine.

Comment: Have you seen this post, looks helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48765912/accordion-jquery-search

Comment: @NathanielFlick yes, I have. i guess my biggest problem is understanding how to get the values from an array and transforming them to the accordions. all the examples i've seen so far are with list types just like the one you suggested.

Comment: youll need a for loop and lists work great for looping.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following possible solution.

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/6v4h7fL3/73/

Switched the Fiddle to use jQuery 3.3.1 and jQuery UI 1.12.1. Best to use most recent versions if possible. Code should work with some older version, untested.

**HTML**

```
<div id="contactlist">
  <form id="search-form" class="ui-widget">
    <p class="ui-widget-content">
      <label for="term">Search:</label> <input type="text" id="term" class="ui-widget ui-corner-all" /> <button type="submit" id="btn-go" class="ui-widget ui-button ui-corner-all">Find</button>
    </p>
  </form>
  <div id="accordion">
  </div>
</div>
```

Added Search field form. Using a form event callback for `submit` allows for the user to hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> or click the button. I suspect a lot of users like myself enter something and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  var departmentlist = [];
  var a = $("#accordion");

  function wrapText(term, obj) {
    var myText = obj.html().toString();
    var re = new RegExp(term, "g");
    var wObj = $("<span>", {
      class: "found ui-state-highlight"
    }).html(term);
    var w = wObj.prop("outerHTML");
    var newText = myText.replace(re, w);
    console.log("Wrap:", re, myText, newText);
    obj.html(newText);
  }

  $.each(contacts, function(i, contact) {
    //insert the departments
    if (contact.Title != null && $('#' + contact.Title).length == 0) {
      var header = $("<h3>", {
        id: contact.Title
      }).html(contact.Title).appendTo(a);
      var details = $("<div>").appendTo(a);
      $("<p>").html(contact.Definition).appendTo(details);
      departmentlist.push(contact.Title);
    }
  });

  a.accordion({
    collapsible: true,
    active: false,
  });

  $("#search-form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var q = $("#term").val();
    $.each(contacts, function(k, v) {
      if (v.Definition.indexOf(q) >= 0) {
        // Found
        console.log("'" + q + "' found under " + v.Title + " (" + k + ")");
        // Collapse all
        a.accordion("option", "active", false);
        // Active Section with found item
        a.accordion("option", "active", k);
        a.find(".found").removeClass("found ui-state-highlight");
        wrapText(q, $(".ui-accordion-content-active"));
        return false;
      }
    });
  });
});
```

The `wrapText()` does a somewhat basic replacement of the text that is search for and wraps it with a `<span>` for highlighting. It accepts the term and a jQuery Object that contains the text that should be searched and highlighted.

I improved the construction code you used so that it's more jQuery like. Once everything is constructed, we apply `.accordion()`.

When a search is entered and the form submitted, we then seek out the first occurrence of the query, open it's container and highlight the text.

This is sort of quick and dirty. It could be improved in a few ways if you needed it. Right now it's case insensative for example. So if you search for `testing` you will get no hits, but if you search for `Testing`, it will work.

**Update**

This is a bit more stand-alone which can be helpful if you're running it in SharePoint where you do not have as much control of the HTML.

```
$(function() {

  function GetItems() {
    var siteURL = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl;
    //var siteURL = "https://reqres.in/api/unknown" //Non-SharePoint URL
    $.ajax({
      url: siteURL + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('glossary of terms')/items", //change the list name
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "json",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
      },
      success: function(data) {
        if (data.d.results.length > 0) {
          GenerateAccordionFromJson(data.d.results, true, $("#accordion"));
          $("#accordion").accordion({
            collapsible: true,
            active: false,
          });
        } else {
          $('#accordion').append("<span>No Records Found.</span>");
        }
      },
      error: function(error) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
      }
    });
  }

  function wrapText(term, tObj) {
    var oldText = tObj.html();
    var re = new RegExp(term, "g");
    var newText = oldText.replace(term, "<span class='found highlight'>" + term + "</span>");
    tObj.html(newText);
  }

  function GenerateAccordionFromJson(json, search, tObj) {
    if (search == undefined) {
      search = false;
    }
    if (tObj == undefined || tObj.length < 1) {
      tObj = $("<div>", {
        class: "items",
        id: "accordion" + ($("#accordion").length ? "-" + $("#accordion").length : "")
      }).appendTo($("body"));
    }
    if (search) {
      var form = $("<form>", {
        class: "search-form"
      }).submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var q = $(".search-term", this).val();
        var aObj = $(this).next("div");
        var stacks = [];

        $(".found").removeClass("found highlight");

        $(".ui-accordion-content", aObj).each(function(ind, el) {
          stacks.push($(el).text().trim());
        });
        $.each(stacks, function(i, s) {
          if (s.indexOf(q) >= 0) {
            aObj.accordion("option", "active", false);
            aObj.accordion("option", "active", i);
            wrapText(q, $(".ui-accordion-content-active", aObj));
          }
        });
      }).insertBefore(tObj);
      $("<p>").html("Search:").appendTo(form);
      $("<input>", {
        type: "text",
        class: "search-term"
      }).appendTo($("p", form));
      $("<button>", {
        type: "submit",
        class: "search-btn-go"
      }).appendTo($("p", form));
    }
    $.each(json, function(key, row) {
      $("<h3>").html(row.Title).appendTo(tObj);
      $("<div>").html("<p>" + row.Definition + "</p>").appendTo(tObj);
    });
  }
});
```

**Update 2**

Ensure you are loading the correct libraries in the head. You show you are using:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

This is loading the same Library twice, just the "min" version first. I would remove the second of the two.

I do not know if SP uses jQuery. If it does not already load it, you will want to ensure that you include it in your header.

If not, you can do the following:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

As you mentioned, in your comment, I forgot to include a final run of the initial function:

```
GetItems();
```

Add this before closing the final wrapper to ensure it gets executed.

**Update 3**

Try the following script code:

```
$(function() {
  var n = new Date();

  function log(msg) {
    var t = new Date();
    var d = t - n;
    console.log(d, msg);
  }

  function GetItems() {
    var siteURL = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl;
    log("GetItems: Start: " + siteURL);
    $.ajax({
      url: siteURL + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('glossary of terms')/items", //change the list name
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "json",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
      },
      success: function(data) {
        if (data.d.results.length > 0) {
          $('#accordion').append(GenerateAccordionFromJson(data.d.results));
          $("#accordion").accordion({
            collapsible: true,
            active: false,
          });
        } else {
          $('#accordion').append("<span>No Records Found.</span>");
        }
      },
      error: function(error) {
        log("GetItems: Error: " + JSON.stringify(error));
      }
    });
    log("GetItems: Complete");
  }

  function GenerateAccordionFromJson(objArray) {
    log("GenAccord: Started");
    var accordionContent = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < objArray.length; i++) {
      accordionContent += '<h3>' + objArray[i].Title + '</h3>';
      accordionContent += '<div><p>' + objArray[i].Definition + '</p></div>';
    }
    log("GenAccord: Complete");
    return accordionContent;
  }

  GetItems();
});
```

You can then review the console and should see all the operations running. If there are no details, then look for Alerts or Errors.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I guess it will take me time to wrap my head around it and even more when trying to apply it to SharePoint. My approach in SharePoint was going like [link] (https://jsfiddle.net/jlriverayuso/wxsfj3h7/24/) but although the accordion works in SharePoint if i try to call something outside it doesn't seem to work. For the sake of guidance how would the search be applied in this instance?

Comment: thank you for the updated answer. I just tried to run it in the SharePoint Site. however it seems to not like it.
i saw that you removed the 
$(document).ready(function(){  
GetItems();
});
which on page load created the accordions from the array.
this is the way I'm embedding it in the SharePoint page https://jsfiddle.net/jlriverayuso/bn1gs8dr/

Comment: @Jen updated. You're right, you need to add a line for `GetItems();` someplace before the final wrapper.

Comment: thank you for the update.I had done a similar change but no go. For some reason nothing would load. if i remove Everything added for the search and highlight  and leave it like this: https://jsfiddle.net/jlriverayuso/huoLfv0q/5/ 
the accordion loads. Still you have been a great help

Comment: @Jen added another update. Need more info to determine why it's not working as expected.

Comment: thank you for the update. with your 3rd update all works great no issues in the logs accordions get populated as intended. I went back to update 2 and deep dived again to see if I could find any errors again. It seems there was an additional } on line 39. now the accordions functionality works flawlessly the only thing now not working is the search. https://jsfiddle.net/jlriverayuso/huoLfv0q/8/ I also removed the getitems(); from line 84 because we never named a function as getitems so and undefined message was coming back.

Comment: i updated the post with a current screenshot of what is being rendered on the SharePoint site with the updated code from your 2nd Update  jsfiddle.net/jlriverayuso/huoLfv0q/8

Comment: @Jen haven't had a chance to review it further. Yes, I'm sure it can be salvaged.